# What is the best way to get rid of mobs in minecraft with mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

This is a follow-up question to a previous question I asked earlier, only I want to know what the absolute best way is to destroy mobs with mods automatically.

I would really like to protect my house from all the baddies at night, if that clarifies. If possible though, drops would be nice if there is a mod for that!

Comment: Any mods in particular? Is it for grinding? Do you want to get drops/mob essence? Any mobs in particular? (as you can see, your question could use some clarifying)

Comment: There ya go, I fixed it up.

Comment: This question should of been closed, it is almost entirely opinion based, and is just a mod rec question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are allot of mods (and a lot of methods) that come to mind. I'll try to list some of the easy to build and fun to see.

From the mod : [ICBM](http://voltzwiki.com/wiki/ICBM)

The [gun](http://voltzwiki.com/wiki/Gun_Turret) and [laser](http://voltzwiki.com/wiki/Laser_Turret) turret.

These are specifically designed to keep your base safe. You can program them to attack players or to only attack certain players and all mobs.

---

From the mod : Industrial craft

The [Tesla coil](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Tesla_Coil).

The [force field (MFFS)](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/MFFS)

---

From the mod : Thaumcraft

[Golems](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Golems)

> Iron Golem Guardians can be placed anywhere. When placed they will
>   guard an area around their original location from hostile mobs, though
>   not creepers. When crafted with the intelligence core the golems can
>   be told to target specific mobs, this includes creepers. However when
>   an iron golem attacks a creeper it will attempt to avoid the blast.
>   Iron Golems also repair their damage twice as fast as the other
>   golems. Iron Golem Guardians may also be given upgrades as shown below
>   in the Golem upgrades section.
>
> Please note that these golems are considered Tier 3 and require a
>   great deal more research than the other golems

---

There are a lot of methods to get rid of mobs. I'm pretty sure i missed some of the fun ones but these are quite effective on their own.

Comment: MFFS is not from IC

Comment: you could also add the turrets from ichun's PortalGun Mod

Answer (score 1):

this answer uses the [Feed the Beast unleashed](http://www.feed-the-beast.com/) modpack, but it contains mods that appear in the other "big" modpacks as well (like tekkit)

- The Portal mod contains the [Sentry Turret](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Sentry_Turret) Which will shoot
  anything on sight. It might shoot you, though... so be careful with that.

  - -not very strong
  - -noisy and very talkative
  - +ranged defense
  - +free, does not require energy or additional resources to use and maintain
- Inustrial craft's [Tesla Coil](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Tesla_Coil) does insane damage in a circular area, but is pretty high level and dangerous

  - -can and probably will kill you
  - -uses a LOT of power
  - -pretty much requires a redstone toggling setup
  - +extremely powerful ( 1 to 2 shot kills on everything except bosses)
  - +relativy large area of effect (9x9)
- The [Force Field](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/MFFS) mod does exactly what you would think, surrounds your base in a forcefield.

  - -can be difficult to set up
  - -uses considerable amounts of power
  - +extremely customizable
  - +'safest' way of dealing with mobs

There is also tons and tons of weapons added by the modpack like the [nano Saber](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Nano_Saber) which makes the diamond sword look like a twig.
This is far from every option available to you in the modpack, just a few of varying levels of difficulty and effectiveness.

Out of the 3 I just listed I'd say the Force field is best once you understand the workings of mods.

**Be warned, the modpack also adds mobs that can be more dangerous than the "vanilla" versions like the [Angry Zombie](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Angry_Zombie) being one**

Answer (score 0):

I personally like using grinders from the mod Minefactory Reloaded (keep in mind it is only updated to 1.6.4 currently)